# IntelliJ IDEA, Open API - list methods requiring be implemented

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing an IntelliJ IDEA plugin which has to generate some project-specific classes in the Java/Scala project. I have a superclass and a few traits to extend. How can I list methods, which I need to implement in a class being created?

I mean the same list that will appear in the 'Implement methods' dialog.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for the IDEA community version, take a look at the [com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.quickfix.ImplementMethodsFix](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/daemon/impl/quickfix/ImplementMethodsFix.java) class for an example of doing this. The `chooseMethodsToImplement` method ultimately calls `com.intellij.codeInsight.generation.OverrideImplementUtil
      .showOverrideImplementChooser(...)` to get the methods. Also take a look at the [com.intellij.codeInsight.generation.OverrideImplementExploreUtil](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInsight/generation/OverrideImplementExploreUtil.java) class.